# Move a node in Quicklaunch using csom

Tags: csom

I want to move an existing quicklaunch node to become a childnode of another node.

Using Server Side Object Model it is possible to move a node to the last position of a parent node.
Example:

```
childNode.MoveToLast(parentNode.Children);
```

Is this possible using CSOM?

Comment: Not really sure what you are trying to do.  Can you provide more detail please?

Comment: I've updated the question

Comment: Not to be cynical or anything, but is there a reason why you are not doing this in site settings?  Just trying to see what your trying to do really, and why you cannot just use the navigation settings in Site Setting?

Comment: Because the site must be setup using code. We have over 10.000 sites.